# How to use Spy++ to find OnClickFolder or OnClickFile events in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows

I want to make a program that can intercept events (something like OnClickFolder as well as OnClickFile). Is there a way [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) or similar programs can do this?

Comment: You want a program, to make a program ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Spy++ can detect folder- and file-clicks in shell windows. Just make sure you're monitoring the right process (typically Explorer.exe).